# Converting a list of tuples with type (Char, Int) to a String in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to take a list of tuples, with type `[(Char, Int)]` and convert it to a string.
For example:

```
tupToStr [('j',9),('x',1),('f',3)]
"j9x1f3"
```

My attempt is below. My problem is the cons operator requires all values to have the same type. So I can't do `'j' : 9 : []` for example. Therefore you'll see a placeholder function, `intToChar`, which would ideally convert an `Int` to a `Char`. Is there a simple way of doing this conversion, that fits concisely into my existing function? If not, how would you write a function to do the conversion in question?

```
tupToStr :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
tupToStr []     = []
tupToStr (x:xs) = (fst x) : intToChar(snd x) : tupToStr xs
```

Comment: What if the number is less than zero, or greater than nine?

Comment: You can use `show` to convert an Int to a String (any showable type, actually)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Assume the number is on the closed interval of 0 to 9.

Comment: @Euge using `show(snd x)` did the trick

Answer (score 4):

```
tupToStr = concatMap (\(c,i) -> c:show i)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [**`intToDigit :: Int -> Char`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v:intToDigit) function from `Data.Char` for that. Furthermore it is more elegant to use pattern matching in the tuple instead of using `fst` and `snd`. So we can rewrite it to:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

tupToStr :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
tupToStr [] = []
tupToStr ((c, n):xs) = c : intToDigit n : tupToStr xs
```

Note that this will only work given `n` is *always* in the range `0..15` (`intToDigit` will use `'a'..'f'` for values greater than nine). In case you want to process values outside the range, you can use `show`, but this will of course return a `String`. With the above code, we get:

```
Prelude Data.Char> tupToStr [('j',9),('x',1),('f',3)]
"j9x1f3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the bottom line to:

```
tupToStr ((a,b):xs) = a : show b ++ tupToStr xs
```

Comment: In that case, it would be more efficient to use `a : show b ++ tupToStr xs`.